# How to create Image view background like this?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-view

[image]

I want to display image loaded from internet to this bg shape. However I tried creating bg drawables file in drawable folder

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
            <size
                android:width="150dp"
                android:height="100dp" />
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/purple_500"
                android:startColor="@color/purple_200" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

But I only able to set corner radius for the bg views. I want to resize something like top left width & top right width. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use svg image please.

Comment: it might help you: https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView?fbclid=IwAR14QgRFgQDZQtyo9BNE5iVNiosxpZifHIOyaXl8_ddFjCKdBhQ4iTMSdto

Answer (score 2):

Try `VectorDrawable` like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="632dp"
android:height="880dp"
android:viewportWidth="632"
android:viewportHeight="880">
<path
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:pathData="M631.712,22.645L519.757,861.891C518.432,871.826 509.956,879.246 499.933,879.246L113.343,879.246C103.15,879.246 94.588,871.58 93.465,861.449L0.461,22.203C-0.756,11.224 7.157,1.338 18.136,0.122C18.867,0.041 19.603,0 20.339,0L611.888,0C622.934,0 631.888,8.954 631.888,20C631.888,20.884 631.829,21.768 631.712,22.645Z"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000">
    <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
        <gradient
            android:endX="315.566"
            android:endY="879.246"
            android:startX="315.566"
            android:startY="0"
            android:type="linear">
            <item
                android:color="@color/purple_500"
                android:offset="0" />
            <item
                android:color="@color/purple_200"
                android:offset="1" />
        </gradient>
    </aapt:attr>
</path>
```

or without `gradient`:

```
    <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="632dp"
android:height="880dp"
android:viewportWidth="632"
android:viewportHeight="880">
<path
    android:fillType="evenOdd"
    android:pathData="M631.712,22.645L519.757,861.891C518.432,871.826 509.956,879.246 499.933,879.246L113.343,879.246C103.15,879.246 94.588,871.58 93.465,861.449L0.461,22.203C-0.756,11.224 7.157,1.338 18.136,0.122C18.867,0.041 19.603,0 20.339,0L611.888,0C622.934,0 631.888,8.954 631.888,20C631.888,20.884 631.829,21.768 631.712,22.645Z"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:fillColor="#FF9DC6FF"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
```

Svg file:

```
<svg width="632px" height="880px" viewBox="0 0 632 880" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1">
        <stop stop-color="#9DC6FF" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#9DC6FF" offset="100%"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M631.71243,22.6445699 L519.757152,861.890517 C518.431753,871.826058 509.956322,879.245947 499.932767,879.245947 L113.343313,879.245947 C103.150125,879.245947 94.5877291,871.580012 93.465002,861.448844 L0.460505474,22.2028969 C-0.756120891,11.2244089 7.15743152,1.33831544 18.1359195,0.121689075 C18.8674201,0.04062482 19.6028377,3.56623339e-14 20.3388164,3.55271368e-14 L611.888044,3.55271368e-15 C622.933739,6.038694e-14 631.888044,8.954305 631.888044,20 C631.888044,20.8844366 631.829377,21.7678993 631.71243,22.6445699 Z" id="Polygon" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"></path>
</g>
```

```html
<svg width="632px" height="880px" viewBox="0 0 632 880" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1">
            <stop stop-color="#9DC6FF" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="#9DC6FF" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M631.71243,22.6445699 L519.757152,861.890517 C518.431753,871.826058 509.956322,879.245947 499.932767,879.245947 L113.343313,879.245947 C103.150125,879.245947 94.5877291,871.580012 93.465002,861.448844 L0.460505474,22.2028969 C-0.756120891,11.2244089 7.15743152,1.33831544 18.1359195,0.121689075 C18.8674201,0.04062482 19.6028377,3.56623339e-14 20.3388164,3.55271368e-14 L611.888044,3.55271368e-15 C622.933739,6.038694e-14 631.888044,8.954305 631.888044,20 C631.888044,20.8844366 631.829377,21.7678993 631.71243,22.6445699 Z" id="Polygon" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This code looks very disgusting. Can you please upload the picture of this code output?

Comment: @ShoaibK. what exactly looks disgusting?
just simple polygon with a linear gradient.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. I'm not asking vector drawables. I need image view in this shape.

Comment: @Spikeysanju I'm afraid it's not possible to do this with ShapeDrawable, you need to use VectorDrawable (create SVG file and convert it to an XML file) or use Canvas to draw it programmatically